# "For" loop for Boolean Variables?

Tags: vba

I have two Boolean variables, namely "a" and "b".

In general there are 4 states for the variables (TT,TF,FT,FF).

I want to see how I can change automatically the variables from true to false and code for each state.

Something like a "For" loop but for Boolean Variables.

```
For a = True to False

    For b = True to False

    Next
Next
```

Comment: CBool(-1) = True; CBool(0) = False. Isn't that basically it?

Answer (score 2):

You simply represent the boolean values as 1 or 0, e.g.:

```
Dim b1 As Byte
Dim b2 As Byte
Dim a As Boolean
Dim b As Boolean

For b1 = 0 To 1
    For b2 = 0 To 1
        a = CBool(b1)
        b = CBool(b2)
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need one loop:

```
Dim a As Boolean
Dim b As Boolean
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 3
    a = i And 1
    b = i And 2
    ...
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution I've found for VBA that maintains consistency with your original code:

```
Dim a As Boolean 'defining your Boolean Variables
Dim b As Boolean

For i = 1 To 0 Step -1: a = i 'this take 'a' from TRUE to FALSE
    For j = 1 To 0 Step -1: b = j 'this take 'b' from TRUE to FALSE

    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Do
    a = CBool(Not a)
    b = CBool(IIf(a, Not b, b))
Loop Until Not a And Not b
```

Will produce all 4 outcomes and then exit

Comment: Improvement suggestion: No need to CBool variables that are Boolean already :-)

Comment: I've not declared them as boolean :) If you take the `CBool()` out then they are inferred as `Variant/Interger` Obviously if you explicitly declare as `Boolean` then there's no need

Comment: True, but your code presumes that they are. You can't `Not` a string, for instance.

Comment: It uses type inference - create a sub with just that code in and watch the Locals window - you'll see how it works :)

Comment: I know it works. I'm just saying that `CBool` is unnecessary if they're bools already. I'm sure you know that. I believe we just have different coding styles ;-)

Comment: I know what you mean - this could go on for a while.... It would work without on the basis of `-1` vs `0` I've just enforced the cast to `Boolean` for the sake of the OP to show a clear True/False output. Completely valid point though :)